# View a PDF from my Android app

Tags: android

It is a pleasure to greet you.  I have seen YouTube tutorials and a number of forums and I am looking for help with my Android Studio APK.

My apk consists of reading a PDF in a webview, which works very well when installing it from Android Studio to my cell phone.  But when downloading it from the Play Store it does not open any PDF.  Can you help me?  Thank you.

This is my code which works without errors in my emulator and the devices that I connect and install directly from Android Studio.

```
layout....

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.crisdanlyt.dragonesmi17.Apu">


    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

********************************************
Java


public class Apu extends AppCompatActivity {

    PDFView pdfView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmnal);

        PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        pdfView.fromAsset("apu.pdf").load();
    }
```

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in English, or ask your question at [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com) instead. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite Google Translate to the rescue (and the 8 years of Spanish I had in secondary school).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Doesn't do any good if the poster can't understand English in order to read the answer. :-)

Comment: Hi. I've seen tutorials and a series of forums and I'm looking for help with my Android Studio APK.

My apk consists of reading a PDF in a PDF view, which works very well when I install it from Android Studio to my cell phone. But when you download it from Play Store, it does not open any PDF. Can you help me? Thank you.

My code, it works without errors in my emulator and the devices that I connect and install directly from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private PDFView pdfView;

        private void initViews() {
            pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            initViews();
            setPdfView();
        }


        public void setPdfView() {
            pdfView.fromAsset("0to1.pdf")
                    //.pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
                    .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                    .swipeHorizontal(true)
                    .enableDoubletap(true)
                    .defaultPage(0)
                    .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                    .enableAntialiasing(true)
                    .onDraw(new OnDrawListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
    //                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //low res
    //
    //                        Paint paint = new Paint();
    //                        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    //                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, paint);
                        }
                    })
                    // allows to draw something on the current page, usually visible in the middle of the screen
                    //.onDraw(onDrawListener)
                    // allows to draw something on all pages, separately for every page. Called only for visible pages
                    //.onDrawAll(onDrawListener)
                    .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                            //Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("TAG", "Complete");
                        }
                    }) // called after document is loaded and starts to be rendered
                    .onPageChange(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Complete");
                        }
                    })
                    .onPageScroll(new OnPageScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int page, float positionOffset) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onPageScrolled");
                        }
                    })
                    .onError(new OnErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onError");
                        }
                    })
                    .onPageError(new OnPageErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onPageError");
                        }
                    })
                    .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "OnRenderListener");
                        }
                    }) // called after document is rendered for the first time
                    // called on single tap, return true if handled, false to toggle scroll handle visibility
                    .onTap(new OnTapListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTap(MotionEvent e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .enableAnnotationRendering(true) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
                    .password(null)
                    .scrollHandle(null)
                    .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                    // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                    .spacing(0)
                    //.autoSpacing(false) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
                    //.linkHandler(DefaultLinkHandler)
                    //.pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                    // .pageSnap(true) // snap pages to screen boundaries
                    // .pageFling(false) // make a fling change only a single page like ViewPager
                    .load();
        }
    }
```

Create an asset folder and put pdf in it

Comment: Hello, continued without working when opening on Google Play